# How to use SpringBoot @Autowired in new class constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I created a standalone SpringBoot application, and created a new object in my main component,
but got a `NullPointerException` at the new class.
How to use `Autowired` correctly?

```
package com.aro.try.main;
import com.aro.try.model.AccountInfo;
import com.aro.try.service.AccountInfoService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MainProc implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private AccountInfoService accountInfoService;
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello MainProc~~~~~~");
//        System.out.printf("account:" + accountInfoService.getAllAccountInfo());
        new ABC().action();
    }
}

class ABC {

    @Autowired
    private AccountInfoService accountInfoService;
    public ABC() {
        System.out.println("Init something~");
    }
    public void action(){
        System.out.println("do action~");
        System.out.println(accountInfoService.getAllAccountInfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Autowired` only works on Spring managed classes, and in your case `ABC` isn't one. To make `ABC` managed by Spring, annotate it with `@Component`. And then instead of instantiating `ABC` explicitly in `MainProc`, inject it using `@Autowired`. `AccountInfoService` can be removed from `MainProc` if it isn't used there directly.

```
@Component
public class MainProc implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ABC abc;
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello MainProc~~~~~~");
        abc.action();
    }
}

@Component
class ABC {

    @Autowired
    private AccountInfoService accountInfoService;
    public ABC() {
        System.out.println("Init something~");
    }
    public void action() {
        System.out.println("do action~");
        System.out.println(accountInfoService.getAllAccountInfo());
    }
}
```

**Bonus: Constructor Injection**

It is generally recommended to use constructor injection instead of field injection. Its advantages are discussed [here](https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required).

> We usually advise people to use constructor injection for all
> mandatory collaborators and setter injection for all other properties.
> Again, constructor injection ensures all mandatory properties have
> been satisfied, and it is simply not possible to instantiate an object
> in an invalid state (not having passed its collaborators).

To use constructor injection, annotate the constructor with `@Autowired` and include the dependency as a parameter. Then, remove `@Autowired` from the field.

```
@Component
public class MainProc implements CommandLineRunner {

    private ABC abc;

    @Autowired
    public MainProc(ABC abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello MainProc~~~~~~");
        abc.action();
    }
}

@Component
public class ABC {

    private AccountInfoService accountInfoService;

    @Autowired
    public ABC(AccountInfoService accountInfoService) {
        this.accountInfoService = accountInfoService
        System.out.println("Init something~");
    }

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("do action~");
        System.out.println(accountInfoService.getAllAccountInfo());
    }
}
```